# Install-base of Java JRE?

Tags: java, deployment

Is there an online resource somewhere that maintains statistics on the install-base of Java including JRE version information? If not, is there any recent report that has some numbers?

I'm particularly interested in Windows users, but all other OS's are welcome too.

Comment: I could give many infographics with alleged numbers, but frankly I'm suspicious of any number like that that's not in an academic journal

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anyone who keeps track of this publicly on a regular basis (unlike Adobe who pushes it every chance they get).  The closest that I could come was [this article](http://kaioa.com/node/40) from last November.  Based upon his site, this data could be skewed a bit, but I think we fairly similar numbers as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very rough percentage of browsers with *some* JRE available at [The Counter](http://www.thecounter.com/stats/2008/August/java.php), though I wouldn't trust it. Sun has a few useful [stats from 2007](http://www.sun.com/aboutsun/media/presskits/javaone2007/index.jsp#stats), but their [stats from 2008](http://www.sun.com/aboutsun/media/presskits/javaone2008/index.jsp#stats) are much less detailed. They suggest that in 2007 "92%...of JRE installs...are now Java SE 6", but who knows what highly technical site they surveyed to get that number.